# Should I make web services for in Java or PHP?

Tags: java, php, web-services

I have a question:

I'm rying to make web services for Android but I don't know which language (PHP or Java) I should write on according to the ability of scaling the website for different devices.

Comment: Java (JSP) tends to be used for large enterprise / corporate websites but is being used less and less, PHP will be much quicker to develop on.

Comment: This depends on the infrastructure the web services will run on.

Comment: Well the webservice will also contain a whole website..

Comment: JSP? I don't know any company that still uses it on new projects. But Java != JSP. In Java, it can be done with Jersey/Jackson. Maybe in a servlet container or in a standalone application. Actually, just use the language that your customer/employer already uses.

Comment: @DibyenduKonar Sorry OP but I have to vote to close the question because this is too broad. Thousands of different answers are accurate here, depending on the other constraints you have on the project.

Answer (score 2):

> One of the primary structural differences between PHP and Java is the
>   difference between strongly- and weakly-typed languages. Java is a
>   strongly-typed language, meaning it requires explicit statements of
>   intent to function and that it is backed by a compiler. At the highest
>   level, you can think of this as meaning it has strict expectations on
>   how you express inputs and outputs. If these exact expectations are
>   not met, the compiler will fail and the program will not work until
>   errors are resolved.
>
> PHP, in contrast, is weakly typed, essentially meaning it is more
>   flexible and reliant on “common sense programming” in how a task is
>   accomplished.  While this may sound more attractive because it
>   requires less formal knowledge, some contend that it complicates
>   certain tasks, particularly in object oriented programming, with its
>   lack of standards.

**Choose according to your needs**

Everything depends on what you want to do on this website.
But here is a Link of a blog that discusses which is better:
[PHP vs JAVA](https://blog.udemy.com/php-vs-java/)